# Extract image source link by regex from img htmk tag

Tags: regex

This is the image html tag from the target web site.

`<img src="this.src='https://cdn.educationcourse.net/cover/educationcourse.png';" alt="education video">`

I set up the regex like below to get the image source link

`https://cdn.educationcourse.net/cover/educationcourse.png`

Regex:

`(http(s)?):\/\/(www\.)?a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)`
--> $1

But It's not working. How do I get image link linke that with Regex? Thank you!

Comment: *"How do I get image link linke that with Regex?"* - **Why** do you want to get the image link with regex? Use an HTML parser.

Comment: is it a full text? or you just want to remove that `this.source`

Comment: just text begin with https and end with (png|jpg|jpeg.....)

Comment: <img src.*?=(?:'|")(.*)'|"   --> $1

Answer (score 0):

It's always best to parse the HTML.  Not sure exactly what is required but the below may help if you just happen to use Python and can use BeautifulSoup...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

# import requests
# r  = requests.get("https://your-site-here")
# data = r.text

# comment out the next 5 lines if you uncomment the above bit
data = '''
<img src="this.src='https://cdn.educationcourse.net/cover/educationcourse.png';" alt="education video">
<img src="this.src='https://cdn.educationcourse.net/cover/TWO.png';" alt="education video">
<img src="this.src='https://cdn.educationcourse.net/cover/THREE.png';" alt="education video">
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

image_src = [x['src'] for x in soup.findAll('img')]

pattern = re.compile(r"'(.*)'")

for image in image_src:
    print(pattern.findall(image))
```

Outputs:

```
['https://cdn.educationcourse.net/cover/educationcourse.png']
['https://cdn.educationcourse.net/cover/TWO.png']
['https://cdn.educationcourse.net/cover/THREE.png']
```